# Need advise about fixing/replacing shed fuse box

Tags: circuit-breaker, subpanel

I have an old house with a detached shed and a damaged fuse box I'm planning on replacing.  There are 3 wires going to the shed and a metal water line between the shed.  I'm planning on replacing the shed fuse box with a breaker panel as a couple of the fuse sockets are damaged.

Can I use the 3 wire feed just as the hot and neutral connections and the water pipe as the ground via grounding clamps connecting the pipe to the ground terminals in the breaker boxes? Will I also need to install ground rods at the shed?  The pipes are within 5ft of the panels in each location.

I picture something like this:

[image: diagram of home to shed wiring]

Update: Added images:

Image of the wire coming from underground to the main panel:

[image: Wire found ground to main panel]

It goes to this junction box, where the it is connected to the wires going to the breaker:

[image: Junction box]

The wire coming in is 6 AWG USE AL:

[image: 6AWG USE AL from junction box to underground]

The wire from the junction box to the main breaker panel is NM 6-2 W/G CU:

[image: 6-2 W/G NM from junction box to main panel]

Comment: Can't use water pipe that way. Are the existing wires in conduit or a cable? Are the existing wires (except for lack of ground) up to the task (what size wires? what size feed breaker?)

Comment: Was that feeder out to the shed run using a direct buried cable, individual wires in a conduit, an overhead multiplex cable, or...? Also, how many amps is the feed to the shed good for?

Comment: From the main panel the wire is labelled as 6 AWG USE from a 50A breaker.  It enters into some flexible armored wrapping and goes through the brick into the ground.  Back in the shed the wire comes up in a rigid metal conduit.  If it was rigid all the way I know I could use that for ground, but since the end at the main breaker is flexible I'm not sure.

Comment: During replacement, would it be safe to leave everything as-is?  Currently the fuse box has ground and neutral connected, what difference would it make if a replacement panel box did the same?

Comment: Does the 6 AWG USE have 3 wires and then have a bunch of strands of wire that encircle the other wires?  That might look like an amor shield.

Comment: Actually it looks a little like the image on this page:

Comment: https://www.vwcable.com/ul-type-3-core-10-awg-metal-clad-cable-specification-cable/

Comment: There are no strands in the metal jacket just the 3 wires.  The shed end is a steel pipe and 3 wires. I've read that since the wire is already there (grandfathered) I should be able to at replace the fuse panel with breaker and keep it wired in the same configuration as it is, and in the future when I replace the wire and run a conduit underground go 4-wire. If I'm to understand that right, then in the shed I'd bond neutral/ground for the time being treating it like a main feed.  I guess that's just as safe as it is already since the fuse panel neutral/ground is currently bonded

Comment: Can you post photos of where the cable exits into the main breaker box please? Also, does the cable just go straight thru the basement wall, or does it turn into conduit somwhere in the basement?

Comment: What's the OD and/or ID of that flexible conduit?

Comment: The ID looks less than an inch. The junction box is just a 4"x4"x1.5" and it comes in on the 3/4 knockout.

Comment: That tells me what I need to know -- it's a 3/4" flex conduit

Comment: How hard would it be to replace the 6/2 NM cable, by the way?

Comment: The 6/2 NM would be easy. That junction box is only about 1ft below the main breaker panel and the 6/2 is only about 3ft long.

Comment: @BrianVanderburgII -- can you tell if that conduit is electrically continuous between the house and the shed? (Turn the breaker off, unhook the feeder neutral from the box in the shed, then measure for continuity between the feeder neutral and the conduit if you aren't sure)

Comment: @BrianVanderburgII -- note that you may have to run a short grounding jumper from the junction box to the breaker panel for the duration of the test (it depends on what the prior installer did to ground that junction box, *if anything*)